# Webpage content - search for pattern & save to file

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, wget, curl

I have a web page, say https://test.salesforce.com. I would like to search for a pattern, e.g. "src" at the beginning of a line in the entire webpage content. If the pattern is found, I need to retrieve that particular line which starts with the pattern and save it to a text file. I have tried `curl` and `wget` but I'm not getting proper output. So far i have tried the following

```
content=$(wget https://test.salesforce.com -q -O -)  
echo $content | grep -i src > test.txt
```

Comment: @Erathiel content=$(wget https://test.salesforce.com -q -O -)
echo $content | grep -i src > test.txt

Comment: Please edit your original post and paste the exact command you've tried, preferably formatted as code. From what you've pasted here it's unclear whether this would even be executed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
wget -qO- http://www.google.com/ | tr " " \\n | fgrep src= | tr \" \\n | fgrep -v src=
```

which will however output URLs as they are written in the file - which may be relative to the base URL.

Comment: Thank you for the response                                                       When i say web content, I would require only what showing in webpage, No properties or publisher details or anything like that. Is there any way we can get that ?

Comment: In that case you need to analyse the whole tag, including stuff like `<img ` and `>`. It is very helpful in these cases to know how the webpage code looks like (e.g. coming from the same source, like a CMS) to see where there are line breaks etc.  If you need something which can apply to many web pages you need a more sophisticated SGML, XML and HTML5 parser.